# Correct capitalization of "please contact our Customer Support team"

Tags: british-english, capitalization, email

What should the correct capitalization of the following sentence be? 

`"If there are any other issues please contact our customer support team."`

This is not a title or a heading, this is the last sentence in an email.

I believe that `Customer` and `Support` should both be capitalized, since it is the name of the team that you are meant to contact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two variations of this:

> If there are any other issues, please contact our customer support team.
>   If there are any other issues please contact Customer Support.

The first one is using *customer support* as a common noun, while the second one is using it as a proper noun.

---

One quick way of determining which to use (although it doesn't apply to every situation) is to replace *customer support* with another proper name. Let's use Mary.

If the sentence looks wrong with Mary, then use the lowercase noun; if it looks okay with Mary, then you can use the uppercase noun:

> ✘ If there are any other issues, please contact our Mary team. [Use *customer support*.]
>   ✔ If there are any other issues, please contact Mary. [Use *Customer Support*.]

Comment: Thank you so much, that has really helped me out. 

I will be using the proper noun substitution test from now on.

Comment: This is a sensible analysis; but I must note that, in the very imperfect real world, people often do capitalize things like "our Customer Support team" in situations where (1) the team's name within the company is formally "Customer Support," and (2) the company wants to combine the officialness of the initial-capped form with the friendliness of the "our" and "team" characterization. Still, as a rule-based approach to handling these situations, your advice is good. +1.

Comment: This is *somewhat* correct, but misses the crucial point of "team". If "team" is part of the **name** of the group, then the three words are capitalised - "Customer Support Team". If "team" is merely a noun describing the group, but the group is officially known as Customer Support, then "team" is superfluous and can be omitted (as your 2nd option provides). If there's a team but it doesn't have an official name, then no capitalisation is required (your first option).